# Embedding stop time in a YouTube video link

Tags: youtube

We all know that we can embed a start time in a YouTube video URL (by adding something like `&t=1m45s` to the end).

But is there a way to embed both start and stop time? Like linking only a part of the video...

Comment: There is such option now, but it is not always possible to use it. According to this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4661905/how-to-customize-an-end-time-for-a-youtube-video

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the official [YouTube Embedded Player Parameters](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html) page, [start time](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#start) and [end time](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/player_parameters.html#end) are both now possible.

Comment: There is now an "end" parameter, though I've not yet seen a functional demo.

Comment: Example http://www.youtube.com/v/r003_FQg4ws?start=6&end=10

Answer (score 11):

Using the information provided above - here's an example of a video with start/stop times
http://www.youtube.com/v/FB1cCoib7xQ?version=3&start=143&end=148&autoplay=1
the numbers correspond to the number of seconds, and you can remove either start or end term if you wish

Comment: this one worked for me

Comment: As of the end of 2015, this still works.

Comment: As of 2023, it no longer does.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.youtube.com/v/StlQ9vuUCcM?version=3&end=16&autoplay=1 
works for me!

as Richard Bronosky said: Switch to Version 3

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? The solution may not be obvious to everyone.

Comment: as @Richard Bronosky pointed out, you'd need to switch to the AS3 player to make it happen, you can do that by specifying the version param in the url

Comment: My attempt fails, [`http://www.youtube.com/v/8lgYfdvC3EA?version=3&start=1950&end=2643&autoplay=1`](http://www.youtube.com/v/8lgYfdvC3EA?version=3&start=1950&end=2643&autoplay=1). I hear only audio.

Comment: Read somewhere that audio only happens if players has 'Enable hardware acceleration' turned-on. You may find it useful to disable this. Right click on player bottom control bar to menu.
Select 'Settings'. This displays a pop-up dialog for 'Adobe Flash Player Settings'. Select the 'Display' icon and deselect the 'Enable Hardware acceleration'. Hope it works.

Answer (score 2):

It is now [supposed to be possible with AS3 player](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters#end). However, I [can't seem to get it to work](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/310759/hack/todd.html).

Answer (score 2):

Don't bother with versions.  But yes, apparently the regular view no longer supports the "end" URL instruction.  So just reformat the URL entirely:

1. where it says "watch=videoID", cut the video ID, then delete everything in the URL bar except the base/stem/whatnot, `https://www.youtube.com`, and then add a "v" like in Mr. Smith's example: `https://www.youtube.com/v`.
2. Then paste the video ID: `https://www.youtube.com/v/FB1cCoib7xQ`.
3. Then add "?start=NumberOfSeconds&end=NumberOfSeconds": `https://www.youtube.com/v/FB1Ccoib7xQ?start=143&end=148`.

I'm not a coder or nothing, I'm just getting at it intuitively.  Also, just to be clear, you obtain the numbers of seconds by taking the numbers of minutes, multiplying them by sixty, and then adding the numbers of seconds.  But you probably already figured that out!

Basically just imitate Mr. Smith's URLs format, disregarding the "version=3" and it's particular ampersand joiner, of course.

Answer (score 0):

Fyi - the above suggestion worked for me but if you are inserting the video in a Prezi that does not work.

Example url starts at 54secs and ends at 147secs works in browser, but not inserted in prezi

https://www.youtube.com/v/zBkdLDpmIqU?start=54&end=147

Answer (score -2):

You can do something like below,

```
https://www.youtube.com/embed/-ZWGpOSS6T0?start=205&end=235&version=3
```

If you want to play a YouTube video from 1:20 to 2:15,

Then start time = ( 1 × 60 ) + 15 = 75
   and end time = ( 2 × 60 ) + 15 = 135

source: http://bloggerseolab.blogspot.com/2016/01/embed-video-with-timestamp.html

Comment: What does this answer add that the other answers didn't already cover? (Besides a link to some other website.)